# Jquery ajax call with class object and boolean data type

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass class object say employee as first parameter and one boolean parameter along with employee object using jquery ajax call to mvc.
like this `data:{'emp':objemp,'flag':true}`

but in controller action method I am not getting objemp.

can anyone help me how to slove this.

Thanks in advance

*Sample Codes:
Here is sample  Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: gridOption.getDataURL,
    data: 'filters=' + JSON.stringify(filters) + '&applyDefaultDateFilter=' + applyDefaultDateFilter,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        JsonData = data.data;
    },
});
```

And here is sample MVC controller which is invoked by above ajax call

```
public ActionResult LeadList(Filters filters, bool applyDefaultDateFilter = false)
    {
    .
    .
    .}
```

here on ajax debugger  i am getting data as

> "filters={"StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"DealerID":"e2a389fb-501a-ea11-a811-000d3aa87c07","StatusCode":null,"LeadType":null}&applyDefaultDateFilter=True"

But on  Mvc controller side, filters is null and  applyDefaultDateFilter value is true

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Usually we ask that you show us the code you have written so far so that we can explain *why* it doesn't work. SO isn't a free-coding service; we aren't going to do the work for you. Consider using a [stack-snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to show us your code.

Comment: `can anyone help me how to slove this?` Unless you show us the JS AJAX request and the MVC logic receiving the data, then no, we cannot help you.

Comment: Updated the question with sample codes

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean - you say you are trying to send `emp` and `flag`, but actually you are sending `filters` and `applyDefaultDateFilter`. You haven't mentioned what technology you're using on the back end, but whatever it is, how the parameters you include in your request are passed to your controller will depend on your routing, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: it is just a sample, don't get confuse with emp object or filter object. I just want to say that one of the parameter is of complex type( emp or filter) and other is primitive type( string,int,boolean).In Back end I am using MVC 5. and the action method which is invoked by this ajax call and its signature is mentioned in the question. Hope it will help you to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

```
 var filters= {'nameProp1':'value','nameProp2':'value'}
```

**OR**

```
var filters=$('filterform');

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: gridOption.getDataURL,
    data: {'filters' : JSON.stringify(filters) , 'applyDefaultDateFilter' : applyDefaultDateFilter},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        JsonData = data.data;
    },
});
```

Actually your ajax call does not recognize the class because it is not a `JQuery` object. So what you need to do is to manually construct the filter class in `JSON` or store the form type `dom` element into a variable.

and remember these controls store only name tags when creating datatype for MVC

Comment: Hi, The problem here is that if I remove applyDefaultDateFilter parameter from both ajax and  mvc, I got the filter object correctly in mvc's controller action method which  is invoked by this ajax call. And I tried with above code as well, but on  action method site, filters object is still null

Comment: yeah because you appended it with an extra & at the start

Comment: please refer new ajax object in my answer it will work as I know